# Populating data in sharepoint - long term

Tags: content-type, excel, data, microsoft-access, multi-select

I am working on a data project that involves entering some data and indexing them. I have been considering doing the data entry in excel, access, and directly on Sharepoint.

Entering data directly on Sharepoint has the issue of ease in manipulating large lists especially if the number of columns are not minimal(or inconvenience if limiting display to a certain number of rows of data). Excel is good and highly efficient, but it is not ideal when the need for the number of tables increase and the data exchange is cumbersome (import works poorly due to data type issues, copy and paste with IE activeX plugin is slow and unreliable unless kept in small chunks - something that is very time consuming). Access seems to be a good candidate initially, but integration, especially with multiselect columns and SQL joins seems to be a philosophical conflict between the two systems that has not been figured out.

What is the best management practices for data management and governance for sharepoint front end applications? I searched for populating data in sharepoint and don't seem to find a lot of good articles - looking for some tips from different people how it is done without prompting a need for a lot of programming support in the long term - which is somewhat a point of frustration for most clients in general.

---

Edits:

Since there are no responses, I added some information related to the amount of data. I have about 100 item types with different attribute/property lists, and about 10000 items in total. Each item is governed by a main standard and can be associated with multiple standards. There are about 3000 standards, which inter-references itself. In a sense, the data set is not that large, but the catch is that all of these will be manually entered so efficiency is important.